# İnflate 3D dodecohedron to 4D hypersphere

Tags: geometry

Are there another way to find the vertex point of a 3d dodecohedra on 4D hypersphere as 4D points other than making stereographic projection. Is this possible, for exemple  ortographic pojection of the vertex points from (0,0,0,0) to hypersphere?

Comment: My question was that, How can I get the vertex coordinate of an ordinary regular 3D dodecohedra in 4d space?

Answer (score 0):

There is a regular polychoron called 120-cell, which is represented by the Coxeter-Dynkin diagram "x5o3o3o". As its name implies it has 120 equivalent cells, all being represented by the sub-diagrams "x5o3o .", i.e. represent dodecahedra each. The vertex figure of that polychoron (4D polytope) then is represented by the sub-diagram ". x3o3o", i.e. is the tetrahedron. Therefore "x5o3o3o" (120-cell) thus has 4 dodecahedra per vertex.

Being one out of the 6 regular polychora, the vertices of that 120-cell all are equivalent under the action of the point group "o5o3o3o". That is, they indeed all lie on the same 4D hypersphere. Esp. those 20 vertices of a single dodecahedron out of those 120.

--- rk